# Is it right to include the url of the projects I did in my resume?

Tags: resume, company-norms

I am currently doing an internship in a startup and it's been more then 4 months period of time.I have been overworked so I was thinking of changing the company.

But one thing I'm not sure is should I include my projects I did in my resume.All of the projects I did belonged to big companies but during my joining I have signed agreement stating:

*All the info relating to the company or its client must be regarded as confidential and must not be disclosed by you to any party , except with our clients permission.*

So all the projects I did were a kind of personal projects like admin panel for a lottery system and some warranty related customer service website which are not available publicly.So I'm quiet skeptical about sharing such info as I'll be posting my resume on public websites.

*But then* I have nothing to show about my experience.

Comment: Some people have achievements that would never even be online.  People found ways to describe their work and highlight their achievements long before the internet even existed. Try some of the advice for that.  Maybe have a read of www.askamanager.org

Answer (score 4):

Instead of telling *for whom you did what*, tell **what** you did.

So, instead of saying something like:

> I worked for the Indian Government Secret Branch to build a special
>   agent hour tracking application at http://example.com/india/topsecret
>   using Programming Language With A Known Security Hole and discontinued
>   Frontend Framework with another security hole v1.2.3

you could describe it in this manner:

> I worked on a confidential project that implements the backend using
>   Programming Language with a frontend using Frontend Framework. Since
>   it is under NDA, I am unable to share details. My tasks included
>   implementing the login system and authentication, and I also created a
>   HTML5 frontend with Bootstrap to create a modern and mobile-friendly
>   user interface.*"

This way it is clear what you did and how you were involved, but no specifics are revealed that could be under NDA.

Comment: But problem here is that I can't produce a proof.There must be more then thousands like me who can say that they have done this,they have done that but what if they demand a proof.

Comment: I would wager most (sensible) employers understand NDAs and why you cannot show the results. And most will also trust you enough that they don't question your description. That is also what the probation period is for - if you convinced your new employer that you have skills that you don't really have, they will find out very quickly during the probation period. If you do have the skills, then the probation is just a formality.

Comment: @IshanMahajan: some people lie on their resumes, everyone knows this.  That fact is one of the reasons for interviews.  It is a time during which they can ask questions to let them judge your skills, those covered by your resume and those not.

Comment: "Since it is under NDA, I am unable to share details" - I don't think you should put that on your resume, but rather just mention it if asked. It doesn't do anything to highlight your skills or achievements, which is what a resume is for, so it just distracts from more important information. It's also already covered by the word "confidential", which can probably also be dropped for the same reason.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen Is probation period there in every company ?

Comment: @IshanMahajan I don't know about India, but in all European countries it appears to be regulated and required. In EU member countries, it is minimum 3 and maximum 6 months - it is probably the same in other European countries too.

Comment: It is same here but I thought it is there at the first job only.Thanks for the info @JuhaUntinen

Comment: If you worked under an NDA, and you gave me proof what work you did in breach of the NDA, there is absolutely no way I would ever consider hiring you. @Dukeling: Obviously "Six months work under NDA" is better than a six month gap in your CV.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm saying include this experience on your resume, but don't put the literal text there saying "Since it is under NDA, I am unable to share details", rather just tell them it's under NDA if they ask for more details than you can share.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think saying what you did is really covered by the NDA. From my reading, you're really saying you won't discuss the company inner working - how they managed their lottery system, or what the algorithms they used were.

I was originally going to write "you can just say what you did". But really, I don't think you can - it sounds like you're operating as a consultant. As a consultant, all you can really say is "I worked at whatever company paid me directly".

Then you can write that you build an admin panel - for a lottery system - for that company, or an insurance thing, or whatever. But you can't really say "I built an admin panel for big company A". Do you see the distinction?

You can also just go to your company website, see the companies it lists as working with, and say "Company that paid me works with these Big companies".